# Number of supported cultures are different

Tags: c#, .net, culture, .net-4.6

I have application which use culture
Where I do

`var culture = new CultureInfo(code);` // code can be en-GB, en-US etc...

When I try with en-ZM I am getting below error

> Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-ZM is an invalid culture identifier

This works fine in my development PC but not in some other remote machine(Windows server 2012R2)

When  I check do

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
```

the count I get is different in my pc and remote machine.

Is there a way I can add these missing culture?

Comment: The returned cultures are those that are installed on the windows, they are not gaurenteed to be the same across O/S installs.

Comment: Off of Igors comment, see the remarks section in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: @Igor: Yes its same. Checked it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP` and both are same

Comment: That is the .net version, **not** the O/S version which is what I am talking about.

Comment: Check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale is present in remote server registry?

Comment: @SonalBorkar: Yes it is